# Is EUM the only possible translation for HIM as direct object?

Tags: grammar-choice, demonstrative-pronoun, personal-pronouns

In an exam a teacher has put the following example to fill in the gap:

> ***Amici Rufi ____ noscebant.***

According to the docent, if the right word has been selected, the translation in English should be:

> **The friends of Rufus knew him.**

So, in my opinion the only possible option for filling the gap would be ***EUM*** since it corresponds to the function of *him* in the transaltion. An accusative, third person, singular, masculine pronoun. 
Could there be another option than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion *eum* would indeed be the standard one.
There are options, based on the fact that the English "he" does not correspond to a single Latin pronoun.
Instead of *is* you could use *ille* and sometimes *qui* or *iste* or *ipse* or *idem*, and sometimes you can drop the pronoun altogether.

Without further context (and there usually isn't further context for an exercise like that), I would say that the two most correct answers are *eum* and *illum*.

Answer (score 4):

**Him** (meaning 'this man,' 'that man.')

> *hunc, illum, istum,*

(also (derogatory) *ollum* Cicero, but this usage decried by Quintilian)
also *ollus, a, um,* old form for *ille,* q. v. [Lewis and Short perseus](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/getobject.pl?c.13:952.LewisShort18)

**Him** (meaning 'this very person' or 'the self-same person)
 See **II Esp.** A By way of eminence, ipse is used to indicate the chief person, host, master, teacher, etc.

> *ipsum*
>   *ipsum praesto video,* Terence *And.* 2, 5, 3:

Lewis and Short ***Ipse*** 
http://perseus.uchicago.edu/

**Him** (meaning 'the same person ') even more emphatic than ipse.

> *eundem.*

Comment: Non invitus feci!

Comment: Etiam placet...